# Saving GeoPackage gpkg file with QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, geopackage

How do I save a file in QGIS as *.gpkg*?

I wish to use this file format because it supports column names larger than 10 characters.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current version (2.12.2) it is possible to save a layer as Geopackage (right-click on layer--> Save As...).